# React Native Cannot Get the Updated Collection - Firebase

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

My app **needs documents** from the "events" collection from the firebase realtime database.
What happens is that, **when I add 2 new attributes to some of the documents inside the collection ("d" and "image")**, inside the app they are equal to "**undefined"**.

Here's the FlatList where I use them

```
<FlatList
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.index.toString()}
              data={this.filterEvents(context.events, this.state.selectedIndex)}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <View style={styles.cardItem}>
                  <View style={styles.a}>
                    <Image
                      style={styles.imageItem}
                      source={item.image} />
                  </View>
                  <Text style={styles.textEventItem} numberOfLines={1}>{item.t}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.textDescriptionItem} numberOfLines={2}>{item.d}</Text>
                  <View style={styles.genericSectionHeader}>
                    <Text style={styles.textTimeItem}>Dalle {item.sH} alle {item.eH}</Text>
                    <Button
                      style={styles.bottomCard}
                      backgroundColor='#9BBCCA'
                      onPress={console.log('placeholder')}>
                    Vai su Maps!</Button>
                  </View>
                </View>
              )}
            />
```

Here's one of the Firebase modified documents:

[image: One of the firebase modified documents]

Any suggestions?